# New page to be created automatically with separate URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm very new to web development. I'm creating a travel website. Hotels details (id, Hotel name, location, description) are stored in a MySQL database. When submit the new hotel create form, I need a new page to be created automatically with separate URL. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Cant you use a url rewrite (htaccess) and have _GET parameters in the url to select the hotel and display as a dynamic page?

Comment: Extremely broad question, with no apparent effort to search for solutions yourself.

Comment: In general you can capture the POST method from your form, save the new record, then redirect to a URL pattern that lets you view that thing. This is covered in tutorials - if you are looking to learn these sorts of techniques, take a look in my profile for a PHP tutorial to build a blog app from scratch - it will show you how to do this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET parms in your hotel URL. For example:

```
hotel.php?hotelID=1
```

In your SQL database you save the hotelID. In the `hotel.php` you use `$_GET['hotelID']` for you sql select statement and generate your site.

Your statement may look like this:

```
$hotelId = (int) $_GET['hotelID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE hotelID = {$hotelId}";
```

Comment: Oops - a SQL injection security vulnerability right there! Always recommend bound variables when running a database query.

Comment: @halfer Yes, its not right way, but the idea should be clear!